# Display value from database inside a Multiple Select Box

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, multiple-select

This is the basic multiple select box:

```
<select name="State" size="5" multiple="multiple">

    <option value="1">Kedah</option>
    <option value="2">Kelantan</option>

</select>
```

The question is, instead of manually typing an option value, how can I get the data from database to be use as option value.

My db looks like this :

```
    mysql> select sta_id,sta_name
    -> from sys_state
    -> where sta_status = '1';

+--------+----------------------------------+
| sta_id | sta_name                         |
+--------+----------------------------------+
|     01 | JOHOR                            |
|     02 | KEDAH                            |
|     03 | KELANTAN                         |
|     04 | MELAKA                           |
|     05 | NEGERI SEMBILAN                  |
|     06 | PAHANG                           |
|     07 | PULAU PINANG                     |
|     08 | PERAK                            |
|     09 | PERLIS                           |
|     10 | SELANGOR                         |
|     11 | TERENGGANU                       |
|     12 | SABAH                            |
|     13 | SARAWAK                          |
|     14 | WILAYAH PERSEKUTUAN KUALA LUMPUR |
|     15 | WILAYAH PERSEKUTUAN LABUAN       |
|     16 | WILAYAH PERSEKUTUAN PUTRAJAYA    |
+--------+----------------------------------+
```

Comment: so what you have tried?

Comment: tried to call function containing sqlselect inside thos option value, well, it failed

Comment: What kind of db connection do you use? mysql_XXX, MySqlI, PDO? You need to provide some more information. Otherwise people won't be able to provide helpful answers.

Answer (score 4):

1. Firstly, you should connect to DB [PHP Mysql Connection](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp)
2. Next step is to fetch those rows and write data to the variable(it can be an array or any object, in my case it's an array) [PHP MySQL Data Select](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp):

   ```
   $sql = "SELECT sta_id,sta_name FROM sys_state WHERE sta_status = '1'";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   $resultData = [];
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $resultData[$row['sta_id']] = $row['sta_name'];
       }
   }
   ```
3. Finally, print them on html page:

   ```
   <select name="State" size="5" multiple="multiple">
   <?php
   foreach ($resultData as $key => $value) {
       echo '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$value.'</option>';
   }
   ?>
   </select>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php $qry = mysql_query("select sta_id,sta_name from sys_state where sta_status = '1'");?>

<select name="State" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['sta_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['sta_name'];?></option>
 <?php }?>
</select>
```

**Note** :- `mysql_*` has been deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

Try with -

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "password", "database");
$res = $mysqli->query("select sta_id,sta_name from sys_state where sta_status = '1'");

?>
<select name="State" size="5" multiple="multiple">
<?php

while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value='".$row['sta_id']."'>".$row['sta_name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $qry = mysql_query("select sta_id,sta_name from sys_state where sta_status = '1'");

$dropdown ='<select name="State" size="5" multiple="multiple">';
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry)){
    $dropdown .='<option value="'.$row['sta_id'].'">'.$row['sta_name'].'</option>';
 }
$dropdown .= '</select>';
echo $dropdown;
```

And this will echo a dropdown with dynamic values

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically you can just `echo` them

```
$dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=x"; 
$user="root";
$password="";
try{
$connect = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password); // PDO= PHP Data Object
$connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e){echo $e->getMessage();}


$select = $connect->query("select sta_id,sta_name from sys_state where sta_status = '1';"); 

echo "<select name=\"State\" size=\"5\" multiple=\"multiple\">";

foreach ($select as $temp){


   echo "<option value=\"1\">".temp["sta_name"]."  </option>";
    ......
    ....


}
echo "</select>";

$connect=null;// CLOSE CONNECTION
```

but constructing them into a function would be better

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it this way though:

```
<?php     // MULTI SELECTION 



    $sql1 = " SELECT sta_id,sta_name FROM dof_perkhidmatan.sys_state WHERE sta_status = '1' ";

    $result1 =  $db->sql_query($sql1,END_TRANSACTION);

    if($db->sql_numrows($result1) > 0)
    {

    ?>

     <select id="State" name="State" size="16" multiple="multiple">
     <?php

    // output data of each row
    while($row_select = $db->sql_fetchrow($result1))        
        {
         echo '<option value="'.$row_select['sta_id'].'">'.$row_select['sta_name'].'</option>';
        }


    ?>
    </select>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked fine for me

```
<?php
<!-- Connect to your database-->

require 'dbconnect.php';

<!--  Fetch required data from the database-->

$sql="SELECT sta_id,sta_name from sys_state WHERE sta_status = '1' ";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

?>
<select multiple size="6">

<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){?>
          <option value="<?php echo $row['sta_id']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['sta_name']; ?></option>

 <?php
}
?>
 </select>
```

Comment: This is a code only answer which doesn't add anything that other answers have more completely covered. (*This answer also features non best practise coding* )